# How to split Proc Freq output into multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: sas, output

Proc Freq provides an output where N, percent, rowpct and colpct are all in the same cell when I export it to Excel. How do I get these values split out into individual cells so I can actually work with them in Excel?

Thanks!

Comment: There are very many ways to get SAS output into Excel.  Show **your** code. Include sample data that replicates the issue.

Comment: How did you export your results to Excel. The output and solution depends on that. You can also use PROC TABULATE which gives you more control over the output.